# Why should I avoid using only one UIViewController for an entire app

Tags: ios, iphone, memory-management, uiviewcontroller

I've been building iOS apps for a few years now. While I'm usually using a Navigation Controller to manage my View Controllers, I'm wandering what would be the impacts of someone building an iOS app using only one UIViewController to manage all it's views. That way, the developer would navigate between it's views by assigning a new view to the only UIViewController.

Let's say that developer is not planning to use Storyboard and that he doesn't mind build Views programmatically.

Is there an advantage to build an app this way? What are the downsides?

Let's be clear, I am not planning to build an app this way. I'm only wandering what would be the impacts from a theoretical aspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an advantage to build an app this way? What are the downsides?

There's absolutely nothing wrong with making views come and go nimbly within a single view controller. I do it all the time and so do you, probably.

But now let's consider an extreme case along with the problem of where to put functionality. Let's say I have 10 different views with 10 different sets of subview functionality (buttons that do things, and so forth), all replacing one another in the interface. It's easy to imagine that one view controller governing all of these might get a little top-heavy with code. If each view has its own view controller, on the other hand, each view's controller functionality is in a separate view controller. This will likely make for more maintainable code in the long run.

The navigation controller architecture is a case in point. It separates the code that performs the transition between views (the navigation controller, which moves views in and out and deals with the Back button and so forth) from the code that implements the functionality of those views (the child view controllers that are pushed and popped on the navigation controller's stack). That's pretty darned clean and elegant, and is something you should probably want to use or emulate, not abandon.

Answer (score 1):

Apple chose the one view controller per page approach in it's https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/index.html. That may be in part to maximize generality -- different users of UIPageViewController will obviously have different needs. But another consideration is memory; if you have a few dozen pages in the multiple subviews approach, you'll have a few dozen full-page subviews, and that's a quick way to use far more memory than you actually need at any given time.

If you do go with a single view controller and multiple subviews, consider instantiating the subviews only as you need them, and removing the ones that you don't need from the view hierarchy. Indeed, since it sounds like all your pages use the same format (checklist), it's hard to see why you'd ever need more than a single view for the pages. When the user selects a different page, you'd simply give the view a new set of data to draw.